# Is it possible to gain multiple Essence from a single run?

Tags: shark-game

So as not to spoil too much, I'll just say that Essence is the name of the reset currency and I enjoy having it.  Is the amount of Essence you gain from a reset (done the right way!  not the reset button along the top bar!)  based on anything you do during the run or have at the end, or is it a simple 1-per-reset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to version 0.7, it was possible to only get one essence per reset.

After version 0.7, it is possible to get multiple essence per reset in two different ways.

The fastest way is to maximize your world level.  As @Chillie points out, the formula for this is `1+floor(N/5)` where N is the world level.  So, always pick the world with the largest level to maximize your essence return.

The slower way, which is essentially AFK, is to assemble a whale chorus.  I have yet to obtain a single essence with this approach, but rumors are that you can acquire them if you wait long enough.  The acquisition rate is quite slow however.  (1 / week?)

Answer (score 1):

As of 0.71 the formula for essence awarded for entering the gate is `1+floor(N/5)` where N is the world level.

I have answered the chorus question here:
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/207292/103772

Comment: 1+floor(N/5) is different than ceiling(N/5).  Are Syade's numbers off?  (Look at N == 5 to see the difference).

Comment: @John took this directly from http://cirri.al/sharks/js/gateway.js

Answer (score 0):

The 0/second is just a very small value rounded down. You'll get about one every 12 hours or so, with no upgrades to it.
As for the amount of essence... after a few hours of testing and about a dozen worlds, it's based entirely on the world level. anything higher than 5 yields 2. anything higher than 9 probably yields 3, and so on.

EDIT: okay, figured it out for real. 1~5 = 1, 6~10 = 2, 11~15 = 3, etc.
a level 36 world just gave me 8.

Comment: You're mistaken about the whale chorus. It's bugged, multiple people report no essence after 36 hours (myself included)