# How to get a Whale Chorus to generate Essense?

Tags: shark-game

As of the recent 0.7 release, one can create a whale chorus.  Once generated, in the grotto the line for Whale Chorus says, "Essence 0 / sec"  ...  Is there a way to get that value to be a positive number?

This is related to, but different from: [Is it possible to gain multiple Essence from a single run?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/192541/is-it-possible-to-gain-multiple-essence-from-a-single-run/197312#197312)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 0.71 with no multipliers (global or world) the whale chorus adds 0.6048 essence **per week**.

Moreover, whale totem has no effect on the chorus.

So with maxed Time Anemone (lvl 5, effect: x10 multiplier; lvl 5 cost: 100 000 essence ) you will get 6.048 essence per week.

Comment: Chillie, how did you determine this value?

Comment: The game code has 1e-6 per sec of essence generation for whale chorus. Game creator said his code was rubbish, but luckily it's extremely readable.

Comment: The chorus generation rate can be found [here](http://cirri.al/sharks/js/data/resourcetable.js) and uprages are defined [here](http://cirri.al/sharks/js/data/upgrades.js)

Answer (score 1):

on the [incremental games subreddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games), to [quote the developer](http://www.reddit.com/r/incremental_games/comments/2punu6/shark_game_v07/) himself:
"Whale choruses add essence at a ridiculously slow rate (something like one every twelve hours without the general multiplier) and were meant to be an optional side thing if people couldn't afford a gate cost and/or wanted to put the game aside for a long time."
Could probably also be worth it in the far future when you have enough multipliers to make that be around 1/hour or something.

edit: quickest way to get a whale chorus is to go to a haven. get shrimp, recycle algae, get sponges, crown shrimp queens... this gets you to a billion algae/sec in <15 mins. which translates to 1b fish/sec for the whales, or 1b kelp/sec to generate sea apples for the science.

Comment: I have run with Whale Choruses for 12, 24 and 36 hours at this point, and have never received a single essence.  In addition, I have a 4X "global" multiplier artifact in play.  Have you seen this work?

Comment: There are people on the subreddit thread complaining about whale choruses not working. But really, they're not worth it - you can go up in levels by skipping worlds. If you have level 4 time anemone, you can probably go to level 1k worlds and get 200 essence per reset - i'm currently at level 250 worlds with level 3 time anemone and level 2~4 everything else @John